# Approximate two integers of equation (fastest algorithm)

Tags: calculus, algorithms

Not sure if it's a right place, though...

I have a formula $\frac{C_1}{C_2} = C = {x}{y}$, where $C_1, C_2, C, x, y \in \mathbb{N}$, more precisely $x = [1 \dots 32], y = [1 \dots 8192], C = [1 \dots 32*8192]$.What is the fastest algorithm to find $x$ and $y$ that their multiplication would have a minimum difference to $C$?

Consider two examples:

$C = 10000$, the answer is $(2, 5000)$, or $(5, 2000)$ and so on.

$C = 67811$, the answer is $(19, 3569)$.

Comment: Presumably by your double periods (now changed to ellipses) you mean a range of numbers.  What does that mean for $C$?  For any given value $C$ what is wrong with rounding it and taking $x=1, y=$ the rounded value?

Comment: @RossMillikan, Consider $C = 10000$, the right answers are $(2, 5000)$; $(5, 2000$); and so on. $(1, 10000)$ is not, because the difference would be $10000 - 8192 = 1808$.

Comment: It looks like $C$ may not be a whole number because of the $C_2$ in the denominator.  It has to be because $x$ and $y$ are.  Why are we talking of $C_1,C_2?$

Comment: Also, how "fast" do you actually need to be? Feels like you can just brute force the whole thing since $x$ only has 32 different possible values... You'll end up with a constant time method.

Comment: @RossMillikan, I slightly updated the post, $C \in \mathbb{N}$ as well. So, I'm talking about integer arithmetic only. I put the constants from which $C$ is derived for, if any, some clues how algo could be faster. If it doesn't help, we may talk only about one constant, of course.

Comment: @N.Bach, This is how it's done right now, is there any faster method exists?

Comment: Ok, so $C$ is computed from two integers $C_1$ and $C_2$... do you want $xy$ to be the best approximation of $C$, or the best approximation of $C_1/C_2$? From my fuzzy memory of integer arithmetic, when computing a quotient, you round down to $0$ (so you take the floor with positive values)... Whereas an approximation of the rational quotient could be closer to the ceil value.

Comment: @N.Bach, yes, you're right. Answering to the question: ideally to $\frac{C_1}{C_2}$

Comment: After looking for a little bit, I quite doubt there's a clever method to find the optimal approximation, especially if you restrict yourself to integer arithmetic. If I'm not too lazy I may share my thoughts this w-e... On the other hand if you're fine with an approximation of the approximation (with guarantee on the error of approximation), I may have something.

Comment: @N.Bach, the application of this is where the only integer arithmetic exists (let's say poor microcontrollers). I would appreciate if you come up with something. As I said above I'm quite limited to a set of operations, though $\log_2{}$ and $\sqrt{}$ (in integer field) could be used.

Comment: One more thing, if $(x,y)$ minimizes $\lvert \frac{C_1}{C_2} -xy\rvert$, then it also minimizes $\lvert C_1-xyC_2\rvert$. Assuming you can store $C_1$ in memory, you probably can also compute $xyC_2$ most of the time...? There may be some issue when the best approximation $xy$ is larger than the ratio, and $C_1$ is close to the greatest value you can store in memory...

Comment: Yes, I can, indeed. And it's guaranteed that $C_1$ is quite less the limit of the integer number that would fit a register there (32-bit).

Answer (score 2):

You want $x$ and $y$ to be the factors of $C$ closest to $\sqrt C$, one above and one below.  For small numbers like you are talking about, you can factor $C$ and check all the factors.

Added after the comments. As $x$ is limited to $[1,32]$ I would suggest you take $\sqrt C$ and round it down to $32$ or to the next whole number if the square root is below $32$.  Then just check numbers for whether they divide into $C$ exactly, progressing downward.  The first one that divides $C$ exactly is the $x$ you want, then $y=\frac Cx$.  It might be faster first to divide $C$ by small primes to eliminate possibilities.  If you try $2$ first and it fails you don't have to try any even numbers.

Comment: Thanks. I've got an idea (don't know if it's right one), so, $p = \sqrt{C};$, initial $x = \frac{p}{17}$, where $17 = \sqrt{\frac{8192}{32}} + 1$. It will approximate my number pretty well, so then it will be only few loops to get closest. Would it work?

Comment: I thought you needed $x,y$ to be integers and factors of $C$.  So if $C=200,000=2^65^5$ you would want $x=2^25^3=500, y=2^45^2=400$

Comment: Yes, that's correct (there is $\sqrt{}$ available for integers), except in your example $x$ is out of boundaries. So, the answer to the above $(500*16 = 8000, 400/16 = 25)$.

Comment: Then you should (almost) always take $x$ to be the largest factor of $C$ that is less than or equal to $32$.  In your example of $10000$ it would appear that $x$ should be $20$ and $y$ should be $500$ as that is as close as they can get.

Comment: To the update: obviously square root will be always above 32 and thus there is the same as going forward from 1 to 32. Additionally the division is extremely slow operation, so, it would be multiplication there to compare with. I thought more and just come up with another approach: start number for the loop would be $C/8192 + 1$. It eliminates more steps on higher $C$ along with stop looping immediately iff the $C - xy = 0$.

Comment: So, $+1$ to your answer, thanks! Though not marking as a right one (yet?).

Comment: And note, that division by $2^n$ is very cheap.

Comment: But if $C=16384$ you will stop at $x=4$ and get $4,4096$ while $32,512$ are much closer.  That is why I suggested starting at the top and going down.  It seems maybe you don't care to have the closest $x,y$?

Comment: Exactly! The point is to get $\vert C - xy \vert \to 0$. Whatever $x$ and $y$ from the ranges.

Comment: Then when $x \le 32$ it is (almost) sure you want the greatest $x$ that divides $C$.  The only exception is when $C \lt 900$, which is unlikely.  That is why I suggested starting from $32$ and going downward until you find $x$.  The square root caught the corner case.

Comment: My simple experiment shows that some numbers will get $0$ closer to $x = C / 8192$, for some your approach will do the best. If I understand correctly it completely depends on the fact what is $n$ in $x = 2^{n}x_{rest}$. I didn't consider non-exact results since for the loop it doesn't make any difference (we don't know ahead if, for example, $1$ is the minimum).

Comment: Actually I don't get the rational behind starting big and going down. Unless you have an exact solution, I'd intuitively say having the smallest $x$ possible would give the smallest error.

Comment: My example of 16384 shows the reason to start big.  If you start at $4$ you get exact division and quit.  If you start at the top you get exact division at 32 and stop.  Do you want 4,4096 or 32,512?  Another possibility would be  $48887=19\cdot 31\cdot 83$  If you start at the top you get $31,1577$ while if you start at the bottom you get $19,2573$.  I thought we were guaranteed that there was a division that came out even.  Is that not true?  I took that from $C=xy$

Comment: From what I understood, $C$ is computed from the values $C_1,C_2$ that come from somewhere else, so technically you're not guaranteed to have some $x,y$ that satisfy $xy=C$. Assuming you get a $C$ value that has no exact solution $x,y$, I have no clue how big the error is. But assuming you're given $x$ and compute the best possible $y=f(x)$, and $f(x)$ is in range, then the pair $x,f(x)$ has an error at most $x/2$. If OP is fine with an approximation and can't afford to test all $32$ values, I'd start from the bottom.